# Shift timing calculation issue

Tags: php, mysql, weblogic, logic

I am trying get shift based on current time. i have a shift master which have start time to end time. The shift timing are like follows.

```
A - 06:00  --  14:00
B - 14:00  --  22:00
C - 22:00  --  06:00
```

i Will get first two shift based on current time. But i am not getting the third shift.
e.g. if Current time is 01.30 then i should get "C" as out

Comment: You forgot to add some SQL that shows your current try.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another record for "C" like:

```
C - 22:00  --  24:00
C - 00:00  --  06:00
```

Also can create a somewhat complicated SQL:

```
SELECT shift
FROM table
WHERE end > '1:30'
    AND (
        start <= '1:30'
        OR
        start > end
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle shifts that wrap to the next day, e.g.

```
where
curtime() >= starttime and
curtime() <  if(endtime>starttime,endtime,adddate(endtime,interval 1 day))
```